XGBoost/ XGBRanker to produce probabilities instead of ranking scores
I have a dataset of the performance of students in exams which looks like:
Class_ID   Class_size   Student_Number   IQ   Hours_Studied   Score
1          3            3                101  10              98
1          3            4                99   19              80
1          3            6                130  3               95
2          4            4                93   5               50
2          4            5                103  9               88
2          4            8                112  12              99
2          4            1                200  10              100 

and I would like to build a machine learning model trying to predict who is going to be top of the class (i.e. highest Score) for any given Class_ID using the IQ and Hours_Studied as features.
Since this is a ranking problem, a natural class of learning models is to use the XGBRanker in XGBoost or LGBMRanker in lightgbm.
and here is my code using xgboost:
from sklearn.model_selection import GroupShuffleSplit
import xgboost as xgb

gss = GroupShuffleSplit(test_size=.40, n_splits=1, random_state = 7).split(df, groups=df['Class_ID'])

X_train_inds, X_test_inds = next(gss)

train_data = df.iloc[X_train_inds]
X_train = train_data.loc[:, ~train_data.columns.isin(['Class_ID','Student_Number','Score'])]
y_train = train_data.loc[:, train_data.columns.isin(['Score'])]

groups = train_data.groupby('Class_ID').size().to_frame('Class_size')['Class_size'].to_numpy()

test_data = df.iloc[X_test_inds]

X_test = test_data.loc[:, ~test_data.columns.isin(['Student_Number','Score'])]
y_test = test_data.loc[:, test_data.columns.isin(['Score'])]

model = xgb.XGBRanker(  
    tree_method='hist',
    device='cuda',
    booster='gbtree',
    objective='rank:pairwise',
    enable_categorical=True,
    random_state=42, 
    learning_rate=0.1,
    colsample_bytree=0.9, 
    eta=0.05, 
    max_depth=6, 
    n_estimators=175, 
    subsample=0.75 
    )

model.fit(X_train, y_train, group=groups, verbose=True)

def predict(model, df):
  return model.predict(df.loc[:, ~df.columns.isin(['Class_ID','Student_Number'])])
  
predictions = (X_test.groupby('Class_ID')
                     .apply(lambda x: predict(model, x)))

The code works fine with reasonable predictive power. However, the output is a list of "relevance score" as opposed to a list of probabilities. But it seems both XGBRanker and LGBMRanker do not have the attribute predict_proba that return the probability of getting the highest score in the class.
So my question is, is there any way to convert the relevance score into probabilities or are there any other natural classes of ranking models that deal with these kind of problems?
Edit in this problem, I only care about the person who ends up the top of the class (or maybe the top 3) so the ranking isn't all that important (for example knowing student 4 ranks 11th and student 8 ranks 12 does not matter all that much), so I suppose one way is to use classification instead of ranking in xgboost. But I wonder is there any other way.

Why not see this as a classical regression problem where you ask XGBRegressor to predict the score column? Once it is done you take the row with highest predicted score.

@rehaqds thank you for your comment. One of the problems I have with classical regression on score or classical classification of the top person in the class is that in my actual dataset, the performance of any given person is dependent on others in the same class, hence a good learning system will have to consider on a class basis, but unfortunately the class size is not constant. Some classes have 10 people while others might have 5. So if i use regression/ logistic regression, I will have to flatten my dataset and this will create a lot of empty columns for class with fewer people.

Why the score would depend on the class or the other people in the class? maybe if you think that the score can depend on the class size or the school district, you can add these features to IQ and HoursStudied and fine-tune your model and when ready use xgb.predict(new_class) with new_class the data for all the sutudents of a new class. Then you get the person with the highest score. And you repeat the predict for each class of interest.

@rehaqds Because some classes might be "elite class" while others might be weaker and so forth.

If you do not care about the score itself, but do care about who is the best in class, you should use ranker + binary classes as a target. Create a column "Is_first", and set it to 1 for the best students in each class and to 0 for the rest, then fit the ranker (not a classifier).
In this case the result is going to be be a value between 1 and 0, and model will consider all the students in class to predict who is the best. Not sure if result values will sum up to 1 for all the students in class (but you can write some code to normalize values if they do not sum up to 1).
